# watir-webdriver can't create "full-page" screenshots in opera 11.50, 11.60 etc

Tags: ruby, opera, selenium-webdriver, watir-webdriver, selenium-grid

I try to take screenshots in opera. But it gives me only screenshot of visible part of page.
How can i make opera giving me "full-page" screenshots?
P.S. In FF,chrome, ie 6(!!!) it seems to be OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issues:

- ***getScreenshotAs()** only returns image data of the current viewport, other parts of the image will be black*

from [OperaDriver's github page](https://github.com/operasoftware/operadriver/)

---

Guess, your only option is to wait for a fix ...